# git merge programmatically detect conflict

Tags: bash, git

I need to merge from on branch to another during a CI CD. I', looking for a way to detect conflicts after the merge thus stopping the process and alerting it. This is what I have for now:

```
#! /bin/bash 

echo 'start'

function do_merge() {
    git merge auto
}

function is_merge_ok(){
    local merge_response = $(do_merge)
    local SUB = 'error'
    if [[ "$merge_response" == "*$SUB*" ]]; then
        echo 'false'
    else
        echo 'true'
    fi
}


local was_merge = $(is_merge_ok)
if [[ "$was_merge" == "false" ]]; then
    exit(1)
else    
    exit(0)
fi
```

But it is not getting the error. Is there a way to achieve it? Thanks

Comment: `local` cannot be used outside of a function, and assignments cannot have spaces around the `=`.

Comment: Check your script with http://shellcheck.net before posting here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git merge` already has an exit code which indicates success or failure.

Either use `git merge auto` directly in your `if` :

```
if git merge auto; then
   echo "sucess !"
else
   exitcode=$?
   echo "failure"
   exit $exitcode
fi
```

or store the exit code right after executing `git merge auto` for later comparison :

```
git merge auto
exitcode=$?

... # do something else

if [ $exitcode -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "success"
else
   echo "failure"
fi
```

---

Your current script is roughly equivalent to :

```
if git merge auto > /dev/null; then
    exit 0;
else
    exit 1;
fi
```

Comment: Just take into account that if there are no changes in the merge the exit code will be still 0, but no merge will be done. For some automations, this is an edge case.